# How do i fix New react app module parse failed error

Tags: reactjs

[image]

Every time when i try to create a new react-app i get this error

The only fix i have is to copy @pmmmvh and babel-loader folders from an older project and replace the one in the current project.

This works for a while, but after some time, it shows the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file path has got an unescaped `'` in it: `require('C:/Users/cnico/Desktop/Nicu's Stuff...')`. That's probably a bug in the library that's doing this.

Try moving your project from `Nicu's Stuff` to another folder without a `'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Changed the name and created a new react app and seems to work.